# É melhor escrever «lo bom homem» ou «“lo” bom homem»?

Tags: uso-de-palavras, estrangeirismos

Em português, pelo menos no brasileiro, é comum usar *lo*(s), *la*(s) e *le*(s) em lugar de *o*(s) e *a*(s) na fala para enfatizar títulos ou nomes, como «eu vi le homem de preto, Johnny Cash» ou «eu tive la melhor idéia!».

Há dóis modos de tratar essas duas palavras: como artigo definido, pronome pessoal ou pronome demonstrativo arcaicos equivalentes a *o*, já que *lo* deu origem a *o* em português e galego, ou como palavra espanhola ou francesa. Nesse segundo caso, seria necessário escrever entre aspas ou em itálico ou em negrito, i.e., «eu vi *le* homem de preto, Johnny Cash» e «eu tive “la” melhor idéia!».

Como os dicionários Aulete, Michaelis e Houaiss colocam *lo* e indiretamente *la* como formas arcaicas de *o* e o Aulete coloca *le* como forma arcaica de *o*, o primeiro modo estaria correto.

Então pergunto: sabendo que ambos os modos estão corretos, qual é melhor?

Comment: Schilive, é "comum" em qual dialeto? Confesso que não me lembro de jamais ter visto esse uso - certamente não no meu dialeto, nem no meu círculo de conhecidos, nem na mídia em português que consumo, com a única exceção do estrangeirismo "a la" ao invés de "à".

Comment: @stafusa, eu acho que me encaixaria no dialeto caipira, não 100%. Mas eu vivo e nasci em Brasil, São Paulo, São Bernardo do Campo.

Comment: Também sou nativo e (me parece que já conversamos sobre isso) também acho que meu dialeto está próximo do caipira (noroeste do Paraná). Não duvido de tua afirmação, acho que apenas não me deixo de surpreender com a variação local de detalhes do português.

Comment: Jamais li ou ouvi em qualquer região do Brasil.   Acho que houve alguma confusão com a língua de países vizinhos.  Ou então trata-se de um [**"socioleto"**](https://dicionario.priberam.org/socioleto#:~:text=%5B%20Lingu%C3%ADstica%20%5D%20Variedade%20de%20uma%20l%C3%ADngua,grupo%20social%2C%20et%C3%A1rio%20ou%20profissional.&text=Grafia%20alterada%20pelo%20Acordo%20Ortogr%C3%A1fico%20de%201990%3A%20socioleto.&text=Grafia%20anterior%20ao%20Acordo%20Ortogr%C3%A1fico%20de%201990%3A%20sociolecto.) e não um dialeto.

Comment: @Centaurus, quem usa isso e eu estamos cientes que é informal, que não se deve usar em provas, e é mais usado em frases mais curta, como “eu fiz la grã criação!” ou “lo queijo perfeito”. Honestamente, sempre achei que fosse o Brasil inteiro fizesse isso. Interessante saber que não. Eu não vou pôr a minha mão no fogo para se é dialetal, socioletal ou al, pois eu não sei.

Comment: Olha, eu honestamente nunca ouvi isso em nenhum lugar que eu passei, e eu já rodei bastante esse Brasil antes de ir embora (sou de Campinas, morei no RJ capital e interior, viajei muito para SP capital, Paraná, RS, PE, AM...). Onde exatamente vc ouviu isso para te passar a impressão que é comum?

Comment: @JulianaKarasawaSouza, quando disse *comum*, quis dizer não incomum, semelhantemente a *anti-higiênico*. Eu sou de São Bernardo do Campo, SP.

Comment: @Schilive mano, eu conheço *bem* a região do ABC paulista e nunca ouvi ninguém falar assim